# How to set Winforms Devexpress GridView Width 100 Percentage

Tags: gridview, devexpress

I have designed an windows Application.
In that forms contains GridView with both more columns and less columns.
Now I want to Best Fit the columns and width of Gridview 100 Percentage.

Comment: To make this question cleaner, please provide code for grid settings and screenshots for current/desired state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
MyGridView.BestFitColumns();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :

- GridView -> RightClick -> Best Fit(All Columns).
- GridView -> Properties -> OptionsView -> ColumnAutoWidth -> True